# Notepad++ cross device settings

Tags: notepad++

I work with Notepad++ on three computers, a PC at job, a PC at home, and a notebook.

If I change any settings or theme I want to get back at home and have the same settings I changed at job and viceversa. The same when I move from or towards my notebook.

I have heard you can use portable Notepad++ in a pendrive but I prefer to not use portable storage devices.

Is out there any plugin for sharing/synchronizing the same configuration with some sort of account on many computers?

If not, what would the the most similar approach for this sort of configuration?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notepad++ has a feature to essentially install as a portable version, right from the default installer:

[image: Installer Screenshot]

If you check that, and install it to a folder that is synced by your favorite cloud storage service (ie Dropbox, OneDrive, Google Drive, etc.) it should synchronize your settings automatically.

Comment: How can i do this if i have already installed it in my comupter. And can you please how can i sync b/w googledrive to notepad++. @heavyd

Comment: @abdul Waheed if you already have it installed I would recommend uninstalling and reinstalling.  You could probably just rerun the installer, but you would be left with two different installations.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed a little late but In Windows Explorer if you navigate to  ```%appdata%/Notepad++ ``` you'll see all your config files, themes, plugins, etc.. I believe you can just copy those to your new portable install directory to keep all your settings

Answer (score 0):

The approach I normally use for this is to use a portable version and keep the whole thing on cloud storage. I use the French "Copy" service for my shared apps because it offers large free storage. I currently have 6GB of portable apps, source code, a shared "menu" used as a toolbar in Windows taskbar and some non-sensitive backups.

Alternatively, use a backup tool to sync the settings, possibly again to cloud storage and again on the other PC's.